# Search users Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to do a user search and edit after I finish searching, but my "search" is returning me "SQLSTATE [42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 ...." I'm new to the subject, what could it be?

my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form action="/search" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
<span class="form-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'username', 'id', 'email', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
     return view('role-register', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/search', 'Admin\AdmDashboardController@search');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
->where('name', 'username', 'id', 'email', '%'.$search.'%')
```

That is not valid syntax. `->where()` accepts a `column`, an `operator` and `value`, and an optional 4th parameter for determining if it should use `AND` or `OR` logic

```
->where("column", "operator", "value", "AND/OR");
```

If you want to search multiple columns, create a nested `->where()` clause:

```
$users = User::where(function($subQuery) use($search){
  $subQuery->where("name", "LIKE", '%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere("username", "LIKE", '%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere("id", "LIKE", '%'.$search.'%')
  ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", '%'.$search.'%');
})->paginate(5);
```

Note: You can use `DB::table("users")` or use a `User` model.

-From comments-

If getting error that `view role-register does not exist`, ensure you have the correct view name, **including subfolders**:

```
- resources
 - views
  - admin
   - role-register.blade.php
```

This should be specified as:

```
return view('admin.role-register', ['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's almost working, but now the error is "" View [role-register] not found. ", This is the page that shows all users listed

Comment: That just means your view name is wrong or your view file doesn't exist. Do you have a file in `resources/views` called `role-register.blade.php`?

Comment: yes i have gets in views / admin / role-register.blade.php

Comment: Then you need to put `view("admin.role-register")`. If there's a subfolder of `views`, you need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks! Got it, after a whole day trying, thank you for helping me friend, God bless you !!!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!